# Plain Text to Duration conversion google sheets

Tags: time, google-sheets, duration

I'm trying to set up a form where colleagues can input times and durations and other elements will auto-fill.

I've got the input converting plain text to time using:

```
=text(time(left(X4,2),right(X4,2),),"HH:mm AM/PM")
```

But haven't worked out how to do the same for duration (ideally inputting in minutes e.g. `90` equates to `01:30:00`).

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your formula doesn't convert to time because the output of `text` is plain text. To get actual time, use `time(left(X4,2),right(X4,2),)` and *format* cells with this formula as HH:mm AM/PM.

Similarly for duration: if X4 has "90", then `time(0,X4,0)` will display the duration of 1:30:00 provided the cell is formatted as duration.